# When wirting json to file the array closes before it needed and added letters

Tags: json, file, go

When I'm calling a function to append one more struct to the array I have in a JSON file, it closes the array before it really needs to be closed, adding two letters which I don't know where they came from, and keep writing the new data.

This is what original JSON data contains :

```
    [
  {
    "name": "Model of computation",
    "starts": 19,
    "ends": 22,
    "day": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Parallel computing - lecture",
    "starts": 17,
    "ends": 21,
    "day": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Model of computation",
    "starts": 17,
    "ends": 21,
    "day": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Parallel computing - practice",
    "starts": 11,
    "ends": 14,
    "day": 5
  }
]
```

This is the model:

```
type Lesson struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Day    int    `json:"day"`
    Starts int    `json:"starts"`
    Ends   int    `json:"ends"`
}
```

This is the funtion:

```
 func AddLessonToJSON() error {
    
        les := models.Lesson{Name: "Omri Test", Day: 3, Starts: 12, Ends: 15}
    
        jsonFile, err := os.OpenFile(jsonPath, os.O_RDWR, 777)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer jsonFile.Close()
    
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        var lessons []models.Lesson
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &lessons)
        lessons = append(lessons, les)
    
        jsonArr, err := json.Marshal(lessons)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        jsonFile.Seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        fmt.Println(string(jsonArr))
        if _, err := jsonFile.WriteString(string(jsonArr)); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        return nil
    }
```

The console output:

```
[{"name":"Model of computation","day":2,"starts":19,"ends":22},{"name":"Parallel computing - lecture","day":0,"starts":17,"ends":21},{"name":"Model of computation","day":3,"starts":17,"ends":21},{"name":"Parallel computing - practice","day":5,"starts":11,"ends":14},{"name":"Omri Test","day":3,"starts":12,"ends":15}]
```

exactly like I want to, But the output in the file itself :

```
[{"name":"Model of computation","day":2,"starts":19,"ends":22},{"name":"Parallel computing - lecture","day":0,"starts":17,"ends":21},{"name":"Model of computation","day":3,"starts":17,"ends":21},{"name":"Parallel computing - practice","day":5,"starts":11,"ends":14},{"name":"Omri Test","day":3,"starts":12,"ends":15}]me": "Parallel computing - practice",
    "starts": 11,
    "ends": 14,
    "day": 5
  }
]
```

Comment: Close your file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your input JSON file is json formatted (pretty printed). But what you are writing into the same file is not. So in `jsonFile.WriteString(string(jsonArr))` you end up writing fewer bytes to the file compared to the original. The difference in bytes remains untouched. You can verify this by

```
    info, err := jsonFile.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Stat: ", info.Size())
    fmt.Println("len of jsonArray: ", len(jsonArr))

    // File size will be higher than your json array even though json
    // array has an additional Lesson, as the json file has indents and
    // newlines in addition to the data.
```

You can fix this by

- overwriting the file with Indented json using

```
jsonArr, err := json.MarshalIndent(lessons, "", "\t")
```

or

- Making your input json file minified

Comment: Thank you so much! Even if I was working on this year for a week I was never thinking that this is the problem